# Multipart request with Retrofit @PartMap Error in Kotlin (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, multipart, android-studio-3.0

If I am using this code in Java then its working fine. When I convert that code in kotlin then I got Error.

### Logcat

> 08-20 23:46:51.003 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter type must not include a type variable or wildcard: java.util.Map (parameter #1)
>   08-20 23:46:51.003 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     for method ApiInterface.updateCustomerDetail
>   08-20 23:46:51.003 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:752)
>   08-20 23:46:51.004 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:743)
>   08-20 23:46:51.004 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:761)
>   08-20 23:46:51.004 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:195)
>   08-20 23:46:51.004 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
>   08-20 23:46:51.005 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
>   08-20 23:46:51.005 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at $Proxy0.updateCustomerDetail(Native Method)
>   08-20 23:46:51.005 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at com.qkangaroo.app.Fragments.MoreScreen.MoreFragment.updateProfile(MoreFragment.kt:261)
>   08-20 23:46:51.006 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at com.qkangaroo.app.Fragments.MoreScreen.MoreFragment$clickListener$1.onClick(MoreFragment.kt:191)
>   08-20 23:46:51.006 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
>   08-20 23:46:51.006 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
>   08-20 23:46:51.006 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   08-20 23:46:51.007 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   08-20 23:46:51.007 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   08-20 23:46:51.007 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
>   08-20 23:46:51.008 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-20 23:46:51.009 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   08-20 23:46:51.009 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
>   08-20 23:46:51.010 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
>   08-20 23:46:51.011 3782-3782/com.qkangaroo.app W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

### fragment.kt

```
    var map:HashMap<String,RequestBody> = HashMap<String, RequestBody>()
    map.put("version",ApiClient.createRequestBody(AppConstants.API_VERSION))
    map.put("auth_token", ApiClient.createRequestBody(customer.authToken!!))
    map.put("customer_name",ApiClient.createRequestBody(profileName))
    map.put("email", ApiClient.createRequestBody(profileEmail))

    val apiInterface = ApiClient.client.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    val updateCustomerCall: Call<UpdateCustomer> = apiInterface.updateCustomerDetail(map)
    updateCustomerCall.enqueue(object : Callback<UpdateCustomer> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UpdateCustomer>?, response: Response<UpdateCustomer>?) {

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UpdateCustomer>?, t: Throwable?) {
            utilities!!.hideProgress(progress)
        }
    })
```

### ApiClient.kt

```
val MULTIPART_FORM_DATA = "multipart/form-data"

fun createRequestBody(s: String): RequestBody {
    return RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), s)
}
```

### ApiInterface,.kt

```
@Multipart
@POST("customer")
fun updateCustomerDetail(@PartMap map: Map<String,RequestBody >): Call<UpdateCustomer>
```

### Gradle file

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1"
implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"){
     exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"
```

Comment: use `fun updateCustomerDetail(@PartMap map: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards  RequestBody >): Call<UpdateCustomer>`

Comment: It's working for me.Thanks

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add `@JvmSuppressWildcards` before `RequestBody`

```
fun updateCustomerDetail(@PartMap map: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards RequestBody >): Call<UpdateCustomer>
```

Comment: Would you like to improve your code-only answer by augmenting it with some explanation?

Comment: @JagneshChawla Thanksss!!!!!! a lot buddy... just resolved my issue with your answer.

Comment: @JagneshChawla Can you please explain this, how and why?

Comment: @PVartak https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics

Answer (score 21):

Use **HashMap** or **MutableMap** instead of **Map< K, out V>** for the PartMap

An alternative way works fine for me. Mentioned by [alex-tpom6oh](https://github.com/alex-tpom6oh) in [Retrofi Kotlin Issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1805#issuecomment-291563717)

> I think it's happening because the Map declaration is public interface **Map< K, out V>** and the out word makes the value type generic. You can try to use **MutableMap** or **HashMap** instead.

```
@Multipart
@POST("customer")
fun updateCustomerDetail(@PartMap map: HashMap<String, RequestBody>): Call<UpdateCustomer>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert with **JsonObject** Just Like This :

1. In Your ApiService Class

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST(EndPoints)
fun apiName(
    @Body body: JsonObject
): Call<ResponseBody>
```

2. And Pass Like This In Your Main Class

```
JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
body.addProperty("key", "value");
body.addProperty("key", "value");

ApiInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
Call<ResponseBody> call = apiInterface.follow(body);
```